# some folder is not in the git index, and not appears under git status, not shows up in the ignore file, how could I add it to index?

Tags: git

I have three folders protected/ themes/ public/
but only protected/ is showing up in git ls-files

I tried git add public/, nothing happen, git status still shows me "nothing to commit, working directory clean". I confirmed these two folders are not ignored.

Nothing shows up when I do git ls-files --others --exclude-standard

What's wrong? How can I add these two folders to index or re-index the whole repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add directories to a git repository, only files. As far as git is concerned directories only exist as components of a file's path.

See also [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)